# What is the advantage of loading AVPlayerItem with an AVURLAsset than a URL

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

As the title states, what advantage by doing one than the other?

With asset:

```
MPMediaItem *song = [self.itemCollection objectAtIndex:self.currentIndex];
NSURL *songURL = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
AVAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:songURL options:nil];
AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:asset];
[self.myPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:item];
```

With URL:

```
MPMediaItem *song = [self.itemCollection objectAtIndex:self.currentIndex];
NSURL *songURL = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
AVPlayerItem *item = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:songURL];
[self.myPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:item];
```

**Update**

Right, after some playing around I've observed the following:

When using the former method (asset), there is one problem with remote control events:
1. Lock the screen and wait for next song to be played.
2. When next song has started, double click the home button to bring up the controls.
3. Tap pause: nothing happens.
4. Tap pause again: music is paused.

Now there isn't actually a problem with remote control events, because it is being called on the first attempt. It's pausing the music (i.e. `[self.myPlayer pause]`) that isn't working - until you try it again.

Haven't a clue why this is, but it's a reason for me to go with the URL-method.